# Strange layout behaviour on android 2.3 When Using Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a layout that behaves strangely:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent_settings"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
    >

<Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/centralButton"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/facebookLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutLevel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/facebookImage"
               android:layout_width="30dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:layout_margin="10dp"
               android:src="@drawable/logo_facebook_off"
            />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/facebookText"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="@string/publish_facebook"
              android:textColor="@color/color_black"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:textSize="11sp"
            />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/layoutLevel1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent_color"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutLevel2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/vkLayout"
            >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/vkImage"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_margin="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/logo_vkontakte_off"
                />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/vkText"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="@string/publish_vk"
                  android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textSize="11sp"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/cmLayout"
            >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/cmImage"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_margin="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/logo_cm_off"
                />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/cmText"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="@string/publish_odnoklassniki"
                  android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textSize="11sp"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/layoutLevel2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent_color"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/centralButton"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/twitterLayout"
            >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/twitterImage"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_margin="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/logo_twitter_off"
                />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/twitterText"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="@string/publish_twitter"
                  android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textSize="11sp"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/flickrLayout"
            >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/flickrImage"
                   android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="30dp"
                   android:layout_margin="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/logo_flickr_off"
                />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/flickerText"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="@string/publish_flickr"
                  android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textSize="11sp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutLevel2"
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:text="@string/edit_label_2"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        />

<Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit"
        android:id="@+id/download"
        android:text="@string/download_label"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        />

<Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/download"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:text="@string/delete_label"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        />

<Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="@string/photo_remove_photo_alert_cancel_button"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

<View android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:id="@id/bottom"
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

It works absolutely ok on android 4.2.
But when I installed app on samsung galaxy ace with android 2.3 the layout broke.
every component(Button,Images,texts) shows and converge at top of the screen . one button on another button and so on

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate this sentence: "It looks just like if the central button is absent. Everything is just below the top of the screen."

Comment: Can you put screenshots of layout in both 2.2 and 2.3

Comment: here they are. I think the screenshots will explain the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing was that when fragment was replaced it was compressed to the state showed in second picture even on android 4+, and when the fragment was added it was ok.

Answer (score 2):

first of all head to the graphical section and re arrange your components buttons texts and images my dragging.If it doesn't work then you can add codes manually
here you go  see this example it works for me on every device. And dont forget to +1 this post if it works for you!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dashLL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@layout/list_layer"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdashhead"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ADMIN|  Dashboard"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etDUrl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvdashhead"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvdashhead"
    android:hint="URL 1"
    android:inputType="textWebEditText" />
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etdURL2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etDUrl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etDUrl"
    android:hint="URL 2" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etdURl1Nick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvdashhead"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etDUrl"
    android:hint="Name" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etdURl2NICk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etdURl1Nick"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etdURl1Nick" 
    android:hint="Name">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etdURL3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etdURL2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etdURL2" 
    android:hint="URL 3"/>
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etdURl3Nick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etdURl2NICk"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etdURl2NICk"
    android:hint="Name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bDashTestUrl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etdURL3"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Test" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bDashSaveUrl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bDashTestUrl"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bdClear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bDashSaveUrl"
    android:text="Clear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/blogout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bDashSaveUrl"
    android:text="Logout" />
```

[image: See this how my layout looks]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:orientation="vertical"` from the RelativeLayout. It's only used for LinearLayouts